# Error while importing psychopy.iohub

Tags: python, macos, psychopy, eye-tracking

I'm trying to use iohub to incorporate Eye-Tracking (SR-research Eye-Link) support in my experiment in Psychopy. 
I'm using python2.7 on a Mac.
However, I get an error while I'm trying to import it:

```
from psychopy.iohub.datastore.util import ExperimentDataAccessUtility

File "/Users/.../ETUtilities.py", line 2, in <module>
from psychopy.iohub.datastore.util import ExperimentDataAccessUtility
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PsychoPy-1.82.01-py2.7.egg/psychopy/iohub/datastore/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
import tables
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tables/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
from .utilsextension import (
ImportError: cannot import name get_pytables_version
```

I tried to install this module but found nothing.
 Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You mean you didn't find the module?

https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=bGw7WtaDCMbDgAb6qo3gAw&q=pytables&oq=pytables&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1l2j0l8.592.592.0.784.2.1.0.0.0.0.125.125.0j1.1.0.crnk_dmh...0...1.2.64.psy-ab..1.1.124.0...0.LZUJpfdZBYE

Comment: I installed pytables of course. error still occures

Comment: OK, that wasn't clear when you say "but found nothing." 

Still, if the command `import tables` doesn't work then it really looks like pytables hasn't installed properly.